# Iteration with purrr::reduce()

Tags: r, reduce, purrr

Given a function `f(a, x) = a*x` with an initial `a = 3`, suppose to have an iteration where `a` is assigned with `f(a, x)` in the next step.

- For `x = 2`, `a` is assigned with `f(3, x = 2) = 6`, then;
- For `x = 3`, `a` is assigned with `f(6, x = 3) = 18`, then;
- For `x = 4`, `a` is assigned with `f(18, x = 4) = 72`;

How to use `purrr` to realize the iteration? The following is not quite right.

```r
library(purrr)
a <- 3
f <- function(a, x) a*x

2:4 %>% reduce(~f(a, .))
#> [1] 18

2:4 %>% accumulate(~f(a, .))
#> [1]  2  6 18
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you seem to be after

```
2:4 %>% accumulate(~f(.y, .x), .init=3)
# [1]  3  6 18 72
```

The `.x` value represents your previous value and the `.y` here is the next elements from the vector you are piping in. Rather than hard coding the `a=3` in the function, we pass that in via `.init=` to it only occurs on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`.

```
Reduce(f, 2:4, init = 3, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1]  3  6 18 72
```